# Sending Jquery autocomplete query to PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I am using Jquery's autocomplete and connecting to a database to grab an array in which you can search.

However the issue I am having is sending the data back to the current file or another php file.

I am able to see that date is being sent, (firebug) but I am unable to echo the information on screen:

```
  $('#school').each(function(i, el) {
  var that = $(el);
    // autocomplete function
    that.autocomplete({
        source: "extraction.php",
        minLength: 1,
      select: function( event , ui ) {
           info = ui.item.label;
             $.ajax({
                url: 'advisor.php',
                type: 'POST', // changed
                data: { info : info },
                success: function(){
                    window.location.href = "advisor.php";
                }
             });
       } // end of select function
    });
  });
```

And on the PHP side, a simple:

```
<?php
      if (isset($_GET['info'])){
     $x = $_POST['info'];
     echo $x;
  }
 ?>
```

How can I send a request and get a live update?

Comment: Your success handler causes a redirect, which SHUTS DOWN your current page and forces the browser to reload it. You'd need something like `success: function(data) { $('#place_to_show_results).html(data); }` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: So for clarification, data is an argument that is a callback which returned 'advisor.php'  html data?

Comment: no. `function()` is the callback. `data` is simply the data/output from the url your ajax call visited, which is passed as an argument to the callback.

Comment: Understood. Thank you again!